# How to get the pid of child process when using boost's async_system on Linux?

Tags: c++, boost, process

I am using Boost to asynchronously create a process in Linux as follows:

```
#include <boost/process/async_system.hpp>
#include <boost/process/io.hpp>
...

  namespace bp = boost::process;
  boost::asio::io_context ioctx;
  bp::async_system(
      ioctx,
      [](boost::system::error_code errorCode, int rc) {
      }, // don't need an exithandler
      cmd,
      bp::std_out > stdout,
      bp::std_err > stderr,
      bp::std_in < bp::null);
```

I am wondering if there's way to get the pid for the child process that was created.  I don't see any indication of this in the [Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/process/async_system.html).  Note that I'm using async_system because this child process is a long-running process that will last as long as the parent process' lifetime.  If there's no way to get the child pid in this case, is there anything else available that I can use to create a process instead that would provide that info?

Comment: Afaik this is platform dependent. So at least state what platform you are using

Comment: Thanks.  Updated the question to mention Linux (although I'd prefer if it worked on *nix systems -- mainly MacOS).